# Parse Database response in bytes to generic struct type using reflection

Tags: json, go, reflection, unmarshalling

I have a query result from the database in the type map[string][]byte, with key as column name and the value as the bytes.
I have extended the parsing logic from https://github.com/xdg-go/strum/blob/main/types.go as this doesn't have any case to handle `reflect.Struct` like this:

I'm calling the function decode as in :

```
// rows := query response in map[string][]byte
var p Person
err := Decode(rows, &p)
```

```
type Person{
 Name string `json:"name"`
 Age int32 `json:"age"`
 Address *Address `json:"address,omitempty"`
}

type Address{
 HouseNo int32 `json:"house"`
 City string `json:"city"`
}
```

```
func Decode(data map[string][]byte, v interface{}) error {
    destValue, err := extractDestValue(v)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return decodeStruct(data, destValue)
}
```

```
func decodeStruct(
    data map[string][]byte,
    destValue reflect.Value,
) error {
    destType := destValue.Type()
    for fieldIndex := 0; fieldIndex < destValue.NumField(); fieldIndex++ {
        field := destType.Field(fieldIndex)
        jsonTag, jsonTagExists := field.Tag.Lookup("json")
        if jsonTagExists {
            rawBytesMapField := strings.Split(jsonTag, ",")[0]

            if rawBytesMapField == "-" {
                continue
            }
            value, ok := data[rawBytesMapField]
            if !ok || len(value) == 0 {
                continue
            }
            if err := decodeToValue(destValue.Field(fieldIndex), value); err != nil {
                return err
            }
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

```
func decodeToValue(field reflect.Value, value []byte) error {
    fieldType := field.Type()
    switch fieldType.Kind() {
    case reflect.Bool:
        b, err := strconv.ParseBool(string(value))
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        field.SetBool(b)
    case reflect.String:
        field.SetString(string(value))
    case reflect.Int, reflect.Int8, reflect.Int16, reflect.Int32, reflect.Int64:
        i, err := strconv.ParseInt(string(value), 10, fieldType.Bits())
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        field.SetInt(i)
    case reflect.Float32, reflect.Float64:
        f, err := strconv.ParseFloat(string(value), fieldType.Bits())
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        field.SetFloat(f)
    case reflect.Slice:
        if err := json.Unmarshal(value, field.Addr().Interface()); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    case reflect.Struct:
        var valueMap map[string]interface{}
        if err := json.Unmarshal(value, &valueMap); err != nil {
            return err
        }
        for i := 0; i < field.NumField(); i++ {
            nestedField := field.Field(i)
            jsonTag := fieldType.Field(i).Tag.Get("json")
            nestedFieldTag := strings.Split(jsonTag, ",")[0]

            if nestedFieldTag == "-" {
                continue
            }
            nestedValue, exists := valueMap[nestedFieldTag]
            if !exists {
                continue
            }
            if nestedValueBytes, err := json.Marshal(nestedValue); err != nil {
                return err
            } else if err := decodeToValue(nestedField, nestedValueBytes); err != nil {
                return err
            }
        }
    case reflect.Ptr:
if field.Kind() == reflect.Ptr && field.IsNil() {
        np := reflect.New(field.Type().Elem())
        rv.Set(np)
    }
        return decodeToValue(field.Elem(), value)
    default:
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func extractDestValue(v interface{}) (reflect.Value, error) {
    if v == nil {
        return reflect.Value{}, errors.New(
            "argument must be a non-nil pointer",
        )
    }

    rv := reflect.ValueOf(v)

    if rv.Kind() != reflect.Ptr {
        return reflect.Value{}, errors.New(
            fmt.Sprintf("argument must be a pointer, not %s", rv.Kind()),
        )
    }

    if rv.IsNil() {
        return reflect.Value{}, errors.New(
            "argument must be a non-nil pointer",
        )
    }

    return rv.Elem(), nil
}
```

But the problem in reflect.Struct case while unmarshalling the value to valueMap the struct fields are unmarshalled as key correctly and the string values includes quotes while getting unmarshalled and due to that the final struct which gets created includes those double quotes at the start and end of every string datatype.

Is there a way to correctly handle this scenario rather than explicitly deleting at first and last position of the string?

For example in above, the `Name` gets parsed correctly while the `City` field includes double quotes at the start and end. The nested field `City` which is a string datatype, is retaining the double quotes at the start and end.
I tried changing the `var valueMap map[string]interface{}` to `var valueMap map[string][]byte` and `var valueMap map[string][]unit8` similar to the caller function but then it is not able to unmarshal the json and returns the error at there itself

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ideally with example input, and your expected output vs the actual output (the code you have provided contains errors that [prevents compilation](https://go.dev/play/p/Z6qxG-ykS5E)]. I'm also unclear why this is tagged grpc?